# weird behaviour of Json

Tags: c#, json

I am creating Json via JavaScript Serializer and getting an JSon String with slashes which is valid when checked via "https://jsonlint.com/".
Now i removed the slashes using "https://www.freeformatter.com/" and again checked the json with removed slashes via https://jsonlint.com/  ,it says invalid with Error "

> Error: Parse error on line 1:
>
> "{"case ":{"name ":"L
>       ---^
>       Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: This behavior is not weird, it is JSON. You turned an escaped quote into a delimiter of your string. Don‘t remove your slashes, you are changing your result.

Comment: Thanks,So i need to verify my json result and since file is huge,I need some better way to verify by naked eyes.i tried to convert it into XML but online xml convertor does not take backslash and if i remove backslash,it becomes invalid JSON.Please help

Comment: **Don‘t remove your backslashes, you are breaking your JSON.**

Comment: I had a look at the free formatter mentioned in your question. Looks like after the formatting, if you manually remove the double quotes from the beginning and end of the string, the JSON will be valid. Have you tried that? As others mentioned, the serializer puts backslashes to make it a valid string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backslash () is a special character for JSON. Is is being used to escape special characters in strings. So before you removed them - all your quotes were successfully escaped. Now you have double quotes inside double quotes and parser just doesn't know how to parse it correctly.

Comment: Thanks,Ineed to verify my json result and since file is huge,I need some better way to verify by naked eyes.i tried to convert it into XML but online xml convertor does not take backslash and if i remove backslash,it becomes invalid JSON.